# Ng-lodash: ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the error "ReferenceError: _ is not defined" using de [lodash](https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash) wrapper for AngularJS as if it weren't injected, but I checked and it is.

But for some reason if I use the word 'lodash' instead of '_' it works just fine.

```
$scope.example = _.filter($scope.mails, {folder: '!trash'});
// referenceError: _ is not defined

$scope.example = lodash.filter($scope.mails, {folder: '!trash'});
// works as it should
```

My question is and I'm sorry to bother you but is it something that I should worry about?

I am relatively new at Angular and I had bad experiences with strange unexplained errors like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `_` to mean `lodash` is just a convention that was used when in was added to the `window` object. With Angular and dependency injection (DI), it's arguably clearer in your controller code to use the name `lodash`.

You can always use `_` just by changing the name of the injected parameter to your controller. Note this relies on using the injection array syntax (which is a good idea anyway!):

```
app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'lodash', function($scope, _) {
  $scope.example = _.filter($scope.mails, {folder: '!trash'});
}]);
```

I'd say that's not as clear as just using `lodash` as the name.